# Is it possible to run CodeIgniter within a TideSDK App?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, tidesdk

I'm working on a desktop application which needs to embed the WebKit browse, so I'm using TideSDK for this purpose. I'd like to know if CodeIgniter can run smoothly on this environment.

Comment: got any luck with it?

Comment: Sorry, this question is months old and I had no time to figure it out. I tried as hard as I could, but with no success. I actually found out that using Qt + WebKit is a better choice.

Comment: can you help me get started with it. some links and things.

Comment: i want to make desktop apps with html5 css amd if possible then php.
As you said "qt+webkit", share some resources if possible.

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwebkit/qtwebkitwidgets-index.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like TideSDK [does support PHP](https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK/wiki/Using-TideSDK-with-PHP), so there is no reason why it would not.

One caveat, though, is that TideSDK does not seem to support MySQL. If you need to take advantage of database functionality, you would need another solution. Luckily, a [CodeIgnider SQLite module is available](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/SQLite), which should take care of that problem. ([SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) is a self-contained SQL database system, effectively allowing you embed a database in a file.)